# .load script is not working on IE

Tags: jquery

I use Codeigniter platform to make a website

I used this .load script to load a different PHP page.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#right_timeline_div').load("/bookmark/right_timeline");
  });
</script>
```

It works well on Chrome, but IE8 or 9 have a problem. When I click the refresh button, it is supposed to refresh the value and show new result. However, IE doesn't refresh the value and keeps showing the first result.

Is there a bug from this script for IE?

IE do not refresh data once it loaded.

Comment: Can you confirm that /bookmark/right_timeline is present on your server? Does the file have an extension?

Comment: I'm curious as to what the file type is, and how jQuery would interpret it with load.

Comment: Can we see a demo of this issue?

Comment: @LeeDavis so long as the response is text/html contenttype, jQuery won't care about a file extension

Comment: Check a CONSOLE log in Chrome/IE and see what it gets in return. Nothing wrong in your code.

Comment: /bookmark/right_timeline is php file where receive data and send result.

Comment: @jake - why are you loading it without the php extension then? do you employ a rewrite rule?

Comment: IE is super picky about inserting invalid HTML into the DOM. Have you checked if your loaded content could in some way be interpreted as malformed?

Comment: I think a snippet of the content you're trying to inject could prove quite useful.

Comment: @Michal what is the php extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a blind tip - maybe it could be a caching issue. Try something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var randomNum = Math.ceil(Math.random()*2);
    $('#right_timeline_div').load("/bookmark/right_timeline?"+randomNum);
});
```

Adding a random number to your request might push IE to re-read the source thus bypassing the cache. IE is especially prone to caching issues...

NOTE: I dont see what your source is. It seems to be an URL rewrite, maybe you will have to use a different syntax of the source request... This is just to outline what your solution could look like.

Comment: I tried this but didn't work. IE do not refresh data once it loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#right_timeline_div').load("/bookmark/right_timeline" + "?" + new Date().getTime());
 });
```

This worked for me. See if it works for you.